# How to build a histogram on multiple variables (1 record, 12 variables)?

Tags: r, histogram

I have 12 variables and one observations.  I want an histogram where on the X axes I have all these variables. Each of these would have a bar.

[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVXxj.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). In addition, please share the code you have tried but did not work. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: A histogram is a univariate plot used to estimate an underlying distribution function for continuous variables. I don't think that's what you want. Sounds like you are just looking for a bar chart. When when asking for help you should share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (not an image)